# Use Null instead of Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

On angular 7 I have the following interface:

```
export interface Request {
  limit?: number;
  offset?: number;
}
```

And a service method as follows:

```
public get(request: Request): Observable<Response>> {

  const parameters = { 'limit': String(request.limit), 'offset': String(request.offset) };

  return this.httpClient.get<Response>>(`projects`, { params: parameters });

}
```

From a component I call the service as follows:

```
let request: Request = { offset: 20 };

projectService.get(request)
```

The API returns the error:

```
The value 'undefined' is not valid for Limit.
```

I think I should set `limit` to null when it is not part of request, right?

How can I set `undefined` values to be `null` and not `undefined`?

Comment: Perhaps this will influence your decision: Douglas Crockford [thinks null is a bad idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0&feature=youtu.be&t=9m21s) and we should all just use undefined.

Comment: The [TypeScript coding guideline](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#null-and-undefined) agrees with Douglas.

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DusCOfyXcAA9_F7.jpg

Comment: Reminder that the TypeScript coding guideline is only for consistency within their code base and "is NOT a prescriptive guideline for the TypeScript community."

Comment: Do you know what the API actually accepts?  Since query params are always strings, you're sending something over the wire like `?limit=null&offset=123`.

Comment: You need to find out exactly what you API expects / accepts, no way for us to know. Your code look like it will produce `?limit=undefined&offset=20`. Does the API want `?offset=20` or `?limit=null&offset=20`?

Comment: @WilliamLohan I am looking at it ... In fact it does not accept null either. It seems the moment the variable is added to the query it must be defined and it cannot be null or undefined.

Comment: @jcalz I think the moment a parameter is added to the query then it must be defined

Comment: @SamHerrmann I thought the problem with the API was that limit was undefined but it seems the problem is with being null or undefined.

Comment: Then don't add the limit parameter if its not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 possibilities if `limit` and `offset` are "optional":

- `?limit=undefined&offset=20` *your code*

service

```
public get(request: Request): Observable<Response>> {
  const parameters = { 'limit': String(request.limit), 'offset': String(request.offset) };
  return this.httpClient.get<Response>>(`projects`, { params: parameters });
}
```

usage

```
let request: Request = { offset: 20 };
projectService.get(request);
```

- `?offset=20`

service

```
public get(request: Request): Observable<Response>> {
  const parameters = {};
  if (request.limit) parameters.limit = String(request.limit);
  if (request.offset) parameters.offset = String(request.offset);
  return this.httpClient.get<Response>>(`projects`, { params: parameters });
}
```

usage

```
let request: Request = { offset: 20 };
projectService.get(request);
```

- `?limit=null&offset=20`

service

```
public get(request: Request): Observable<Response>> {
  const parameters = { 'limit': request.limit ? String(request.limit) : 'null', 'offset': request.offset ? String(request.offset) : 'null' };
  return this.httpClient.get<Response>>(`projects`, { params: parameters });
}
```

usage

```
let request: Request = { offset: 20 };
projectService.get(request);
```

Use what ever the API wants.

Answer (score 4):

```
let request: Request = { offset: 20, limit : null };
```

---

> 0 vs null vs undefined
>   [image: Just to add more fun to it]

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
const parameters = { 'limit': request.limit && typeof request.limit === "number" ? String(request.limit) : null, 
                     'offset': request.offset && typeof request.offset === "number" ? String(request.offset) : null };
```

Comment: What if `limit` is `0`?  I think you might want to check `typeof request.limit === "number"`.

Comment: Does Angular httpClient.get() accept `null` get parameters in `--strictNullChecks` mode?

Comment: you'd need to use `'null'` not `null` in the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the APIs, the limit parameter is compulsory so that it can return back the number of items as you have requested as the limit. But if you think this API can handle null as the limit value you can use the ternary operator to check the value of `request.limit` if it's not undefined then `String(request.limit)` else set limit to null. You can do the same for `offset`

```
public get(request: Request): Observable<Response>> {

  const parameters = { 'limit': request.limit ? String(request.limit) : null, 'offset': request.offset ? String(request.offset) : null };

  return this.httpClient.get<Response>>(`projects`, { params: parameters });

}
```

Comment: The type would need to change to `interface Request { limit: number | null; offset: number | null; }`

Comment: What's the diference of having `interface Request { limit?: number; offset?: number }`. Your option defines null as a defined value correct?

Comment: `limit?: number;` is the same as `limit: number | undefined;`, `limit: number | null;` means it has to be defined.

Comment: but looking at it now that's the parameters not the `Request` type so actual the `Request` type is fine but you'd need to use `'null'` not `null` in the conditional statement.